# How can I limit text index in Liquibase and MySQL

Tags: mysql, indexing, size, liquibase

When you have chengeset:

```
<changeSet id="some.change.set" author="me">
    <createTable tableName="some_table">
        <column name="id" type="CHAR(36)">
            <constraints primaryKey="true"/>
        </column>
        <column name="ref_id" type="CHAR(36)">
            <constraints nullable="false"/>
        </column>
        <column name="path" type="VARCHAR(5000)"> <!-- very long column -->
            <constraints nullable="false"/>
        </column>
    </createTable>
    
    <createIndex tableName="some_table" indexName="some_table_long_index">
        <column name="ref_id" />
        <column name="path" />
    </createIndex>
</changeSet>
```

And when you will execute it, you will get error similar to:

```
Error Code: 1071. Specified key was too long; max key length is 3072 bytes
```

This happens because your index is too long. You have to limit it.

Answer (score 1):

To limit our index you need to put size limit on it. Unfortunately Liquibase doesn't support it, but there is a workaround:

```
    <createIndex tableName="some_table" indexName="some_table_long_index">
        <column name="ref_id"/>
        <column name="path"/>
    </createIndex>
    <modifySql dbms="mysql">
        <replace replace="`path`" with="`path`(700)"/> <!-- "700" limits index size -->
    </modifySql>
```

I've searched this very long time, so I'm putting solution here.
Maybe it will help to somebody.